# Are Questions on Supply Chain Management on topic?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

I noticed there are some questions that are more specifically in the category of supply chain management floating around the site. Namely:

[How to proceed with safety stock calculation when demand is constantly fluctuating?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/20635/how-to-proceed-with-safety-stock-calculation-when-demand-is-constantly-fluctuati)

[What is the LME warehouse stocks level and is there any common behavior to correlate with price?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/10124/what-is-the-lme-warehouse-stocks-level-and-is-there-any-common-behavior-to-corre)

I just want to know what to know how to the community feels regarding this and whether or not we should have a policy for or against these types of question.

A little bit of an obscure post but I feel its worth mentioning.

Comment: I believe they would be more on topic on [OR.SE](https://or.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

The first question is "business economics", in that it is Inventory management at its most applied version. It is something that needs a specialized consultant, so I would say it is essentially off-topic, given what the OP asks, even tough the general subject "Inventory Fluctuations and Management" is certainly on-topic.

The 2nd question asks questions about a specific stock market (LME = London metal Exchange) so it could certainly be asked over at https://quant.stackexchange.com/

It too has a strong applied aspect, not so much about time-series econometrics but rather on the specifics on the specific market. So again, it looks essentially off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

I would say neither of these are on-topic, at least I have never encountered anything like this during my economics education.

I could be wrong, perhaps it is a specific subject that is still known to a fair amount of economists.